# Localhost routing works fine but the route doesn't work after deploying to vercel

Tags: node.js, express, configuration, vercel

```js
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
      {
          "src": "./index.js",
          "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
  ],
  "routes": [
      {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "/"
      }
  ]
}
```

Localhost routing works fine but does not work after placing '/' in root vs. I have configured the config file correctly in Vercel and after that, it is working course. I do not know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the file of the app you're running in your case `index.js` in your `routes`, like this:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
      {
          "src": "./index.js",
          "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
  ],
  "routes": [
      {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "index.js"
      }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps